# how to create a BAT file to be used in monetdb bulk load from a Java program

Tags: monetdb

I have a file with a list of string (one cloumn).
File example

```
sdfsdfsdf
hfhfhfghf
dfgdggdfg
pookokkoo
```

base on the documentation on monetdb web site, I have to create a BAT file.

How do I convert my file with strings into a BAT file ready to be imported in monetdb?
How do I do this from Java?

Thanks,

monetdb site doc
http://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Cookbooks/SQLrecipies/BinaryBulkLoad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Documentation:

For variable length strings, the file should have one C-based string value per line, terminated by a newline, and it is processed without escape character conversion.

**Since this is exactly the format that you have, you can use it directly.**

A technical note on the side: Strings in MonetDB are dictionary compressed which makes it really hard to generate the binary representation "by hand".

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I'm still a little confuse. by "use it directly" I just write the string as bytes to file terminated with a '\n' and that should work? If you can provide some code would be great. (1 line code more than 1 millon words) Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it should work exactly like that. Here is your line of code:  `copy into yourTableWithExactlyOneColumn from ('yourfile');`.  If you have more than one column you have to fill all of them at once, like this:  `copy into yourTableWithTwocolumns from ('yourfile', 'yourSecondFile');`.  In this case the braces are important.

Answer (score 0):

The MonetDB's documentation says: "Copying binary files: Migration of tables between MonetDB/SQL instances can be sped up using the binary COPY INTO/FROM format. See  the recipe for this functionality.", however, it does not say **how I can dump the data in binary format**. How can I do it? I expected something like: "copy binary from TABLE to "file(s)"; and then "copy binary into TABLE from ('file(s)');